# How to cat or echo everything between two words in a file

Tags: awk, sed, echo, cat

How to cat or echo everything between two words in a file ?

eg

```
df
df
Instance 
d
f
g
end
```

So I want everything between Instance and end

Thanks

Comment: 1) are teh delimiter always on the same line ? 2) is there only 1 occurrence per line or could itbe that several are present ?

Comment: Adding code tags show that data is in on `column` not one `row`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^Instance/,/^end/{//d;p}' file
```

or as Glenn pointed out:

```
sed -n '/^Instance/,/^end/{//!p}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be correct `awk`

```
awk '/end/{f=0} f; /Instance/{f=1}' file
d
f
g
```

PS, data was not in one line.  OP was missing code tags, so showed all in one line ...

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{match($0,/Instance(.*)end/,a); print a[1]}' input.txt
```

Output:

```
 d f g
```

Comment: If there are more than one `end`, `.*` this greedy star will eat everything.  But anyway, its wrong approach of you look at corrected data in OPs question.

Comment: If there are more then one `end` or `Instance`, then we should know what is the desired behavior, find longest, shortest, nth occurrence

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/^Instance/,/^end/{/^Instance/!{/^end/!p}}' file
d
f
g
```